# REST API: sending server time in a header

Tags: rest, api, http-headers, timestamp

I'm developing a REST API and I'm serving the user with only resources that were updated, in this way:

```
www.api.example.com/resources?lastTime=1476952629
```

How can I send the user the server time, so that he can use this timestamp along with next request? Additional field in an envelope is an option, but maybe one of the headers is destined for such a use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Last-Modified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) header supplies the client with the server time for the last known modification. I would suggest using either the [`Last-Modified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) or the [`ETag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) header.

- [`Last-Modified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) with [`If-Unmodified-Since`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Unmodified-since) if you want to differentiate changes by the last modification time.
- [`ETag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) with [`If-None-Match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-None-Match) if you would like to differentiate changes by the content itself, for example by the sha256 checksum (by the checksum of the Last-Modified date).

For browser caching you must send some caching instructions with your answer, most times I use something like:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=1;must-revalidate;private
Expires: -1
```

Comment: that's the correct answer. Though I changed the design and use Java 8 OffsetDateTime type so that client can send his local time in ISO 8601, and the server side translates this to UTC for any comparison. java.time is great